# Getting the CurrencySymbol of PlutusV2 MintingPolicy

Tags: plutus, mintingpolicy

I'd like to get the `CurrencySymbol` of a `PlutusV2` `MintingPolicy`. There's a function defined in `Plutus.Script.Utils.Scripts` with the following signature:

`scriptCurrencySymbol :: Versioned MintingPolicy -> CurrencySymbol`

But I have no idea how get the `Versioned MintingPolicy` of a `MintingPolicy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Plutus.Script.Utils.V2.Scripts.scriptCurrencySymbol`